# Changing the object color when its touched in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch

I want to change the object color when its touched, with the color that I previously choosed by Button(Color).

Comment: Which one are you having problem doing? Detecting touch or Changing color? What is the Object? 3D,2D Sprite? Add code to your question. Put some effort!

Comment: having trouble to detect which object was touched

Answer (score 1):

this will just show you one way to change color of object.

```
     void OnMouseOver()
 {
      if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
      {
          renderer.material.color = Color.blue;
      }
 }
```

Comment: I want to change the color of object that was touched.Your code changes the color when I touch anywhere on screen not on object

Comment: This is what you are looking for. Put this in a script on your object you want to change colour. The object will then change colour whenever you click on it.

Comment: I tried this.Wherever I touch the screen the color of object is changing.I want just on object touch to change the color

Answer (score 0):

Add Component BoxCollider to object  resize BoxCollider make it as big as object or a little big than object
try this code again:
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ChangeCubeColor : MonoBehaviour {

```
private int clickCount = 0;
private MeshRenderer render;
private float red = 0.0f;
private float green = 0.0f;
private float blue = 0.0f;
void Start()
{
    render = GetComponent<MeshRenderer>();
}
void OnMouseOver()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        if (clickCount % 2 != 0)
        {
            render.material.color = Color.red;
        }
        else
        {
            Color color = new Color(red,green,blue);
            render.material.color = color;
            red += 0.1f;
            blue += 0.2f;
            green += 0.3f;
        }
        ++clickCount;
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
try like this:
 void OnGUI()
{
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(100,100,200,50),"Red"))
    {
        render.material.color = Color.red;
    }
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(100,50,200,50),"Blue"))
    {
        render.material.color = Color.blue;
    }
    if(GUI.Button(new Rect(100,150,200,50),"Green"))
    {
        render.material.color = Color.green;
    }
}
```